# cypher creating a node of type actor

Tags: neo4j

from the cypher documentation, it gives the following running code

```
CREATE (n:Actor { name:"Tom Hanks" });
```

My question is, what is **"n"**.  it doesn't seem to be used in any subsequent example code and is not explained.

the original documentation is here

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypherdoc-create-nodes-and-relationships.html

Another point that is unclear to me is does "n:Actor" set the label of the node??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out what the **"n"** means.

**n** can be thought of assigning the result of the CREATE to a variable n. n can then be reused/referenced later on in the cypher.

a more meaningful name rather than n may have been **"actor"**

And the `:Actor` does set the label of the node to Actor